# How to execute a stored procedure in Azure Databricks PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am able to execute a simple SQL statement using PySpark in Azure Databricks but I want to execute a stored procedure instead. Below is the PySpark code I tried.

```
#initialize pyspark
import findspark
findspark.init('C:\Spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7')
#import required modules
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import *
import pandas as pd

#Create spark configuration object
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("My app")
#Create spark context and sparksession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

table = "dbo.test"
#read table data into a spark dataframe
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Demo;integratedSecurity=true;") \
    .option("dbtable", table) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()

#show the data loaded into dataframe
#jdbcDF.show()
sqlQueries="execute testJoin"
resultDF=spark.sql(sqlQueries)
resultDF.show(resultDF.count(),False)
```

This doesn't work — how do I do it?

Comment: The documentation (from the [tag:pyspark-sql] tag page) at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html does not mention stored procedures.  You'll have to explore harder, I suspect.  I've not checked how current 1.6.2 is.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is still looking for a method on how to do this, it's possible to use the built-in jdbc-connector of you spark session. Following code sample will do the trick:

```py
import msal

# Set url & credentials
jdbc_url = ...
tenant_id = ...
sp_client_id = ...
sp_client_secret = ...

# Write your SQL statement as a string
name = "Some passed value"

statement = f"""
EXEC Staging.SPR_InsertDummy
  @Name = '{name}'
"""

# Generate an OAuth2 access token for service principal
authority = f"https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(sp_client_id, sp_client_secret, authority)
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes="https://database.windows.net/.default")["access_token"]

# Create a spark properties object and pass the access token
properties = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()
properties.setProperty("accessToken", token)

# Fetch the driver manager from your spark context
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager

# Create a connection object and pass the properties object
con = driver_manager.getConnection(jdbc_url, properties)

# Create callable statement and execute it
exec_statement = con.prepareCall(statement)
exec_statement.execute()

# Close connections
exec_statement.close()
con.close()
```

For more information and a similar method using SQL-user credentials to connect over JDBC, or on how to take return parameters, I'd suggest you take a look at this blogpost:

https://medium.com/delaware-pro/executing-ddl-statements-stored-procedures-on-sql-server-using-pyspark-in-databricks-2b31d9276811

Answer (score 5):

Running a stored procedure through a JDBC connection from azure databricks is not supported as of now. But your options are:

1. Use a `pyodbc` library to connect and execute your procedure. But by using this library, it means that you will be running your code on the driver node while all your workers are idle. See this article for details.
   https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark
2. Use a `SQL` table function rather than procedures. In a sense, you can use anything that you can use in the `FORM` clause of a SQL query.
3. Since you are in an azure environment, then using a combination of azure data factory (to execute your procedure) and azure databricks can help you to build pretty powerful pipelines.

Comment: @BIcube- thanks for response. If I execute SQL select statement from Databricks, will it faster than direct execution on database server?
In other words, which will be better direct select/insert statement execution in database or using databricks sparks nodes?

Comment: Has this changed since Databricks SQL became GA?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the top answer shows how to execute a command/stored procedure but not how to get the result if the stored procedure returns a table. This is the first result on Google for me, so hope this helps someone.

### Solution

The reason executing the stored procedure fails in the first place is that spark parenthesizes the query and assigns it to an alias (`select * from (query)`). More details on that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75330385/19871699

I have two different sets of code one pyspark, one scala. Both do the same thing using the jdbc driver. I like the scala better. Right now it requires the dataset to fit in memory but you can do stuff with batching to work around it.

A lot of the documentation on how to use the driver is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Both sets of code:

1. create a connection object to the server
2. make a sql query statement and execute it
3. fetch a metadata and result set
4. extract information on the columns/count
5. loop through every row of the result set and every field within it to extract the values, populating a row list for the fields, and then appending it to the rows list.
6. Convert the resulting list of lists into a dataframe

#### Python

There's an issue with dates staying a JavaObject type although pandas reads it just fine. If you did spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(...)) it'd complain about the type, but an intermediary csv works.

*I use the getObject because it extracts whatever the result is. There are other methods like getString,getFloat,... that would be better*

This is the worst possible scenario though for py4j. You are serializing every single value in the entire table one by one to send from scala over to python.

```
%python
import pandas as pd

# parameters
username = ""
password = ""
host = ""
port = ""
database = ""

query = """
exec ...
"""

# construct jdbc url
sqlsUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port};database={database}"


# get the gateway/connection to py4j
gateway = sc._gateway
jvm = gateway.jvm

# connection to the server
con = jvm.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(sqlsUrl, username,password)


# create a statement, execute it, get result set and metadata
statement = con.prepareCall(query)
statement.execute()

metadata = statement.getMetaData()
resultset = statement.getResultSet()

# extract column names from metadata
columns = [metadata.getColumnName(i+1) for i in range(metadata.getColumnCount())]


# loop through the result set and make into a list of lists
rows = []
while resultset.next():
    row = []
    for i in range(len(columns)):
        row.append(resultset.getObject(i+1))
    rows.append(row)

# close the connection
con.close()

# make into a pandas dataframe and write temporarily to a csv (bug with date)
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns).to_csv("tmp.csv",index=False)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv("tmp.csv"))

# voila
display(df)
```

#### Scala

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet

// connection parameters
val username = ""
val password = ""
val host = ""
val port = ""
val database = ""

val sqlsUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://$host:$port;databaseName=$database"

// query
val query = """
exec ..
"""

// get connection
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlsUrl, username,password)

// prepare statement and execute it
val statement = connection.prepareCall(query)
statement.executeQuery()


// fetch results and the structure of the results
val metaData = statement.getMetaData()
val resultSet = statement.getResultSet()
val indices = (1 to metaData.getColumnCount).toList

// translation of java types to spark types
val columnTypesSpark = Map(
    "java.lang.String"-> StringType,
    "java.lang.Short"-> ShortType,
    "java.sql.Date"-> DateType,
    "java.sql.Timestamp"-> TimestampType,
    "java.math.BigDecimal"-> DecimalType(10,1), // whatever precision you want
    "java.lang.Float" -> FloatType,
    "java.lang.Integer" -> IntegerType,
    "java.lang.Boolean" -> BooleanType)


// list out the column types in the returned data
val columnTypes = indices.map(i => columnTypesSpark(metaData.getColumnClassName(i)) )

// list out the column names in the returned data
val columnNames = indices.map(i => metaData.getColumnLabel(i))

// define the schema
val schema = StructType(indices.map(i => StructField(columnNames(i-1),columnTypes(i-1)) ))

// loop through the results dataset
val results: List[Row] = Iterator
  .continually {
    if (resultSet.next()) Some(Row(indices.map(o => resultSet.getObject(o)).toList:_*))
    else None
  }
  .takeWhile(_.isDefined)
  .map(_.get)
  .toList

// close connection
con.close()

// convert results rowset into an RDD and then assign results into a dataframe
val df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(results),schema)

display(df)
```

Long answer. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This is throwing error for Python in Unit Catalog: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public static java.sql.Connection java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException is not whitelisted on class class java.sql.DriverManager