# How to drop index on database table from PySpark?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, indexing, pyspark

I'm trying to drop index from a database table and want to create a new index from PySpark.

```py
indexStatment = "ALTER TABLE cust_line DROP INDEX cust_line_clm_id_idx"

sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demotable",driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",query=indexStatment ,user="root",password="root", useSSL = False).load()
```

Can anyone tell how to drop an index on a database table from PySpark?

Comment: I'm not sure you can even execute DDL through PySpark, because the function you're using is for reading query results, and `ALTER TABLE` (or `DROP INDEX`) is not a query.

Comment: Similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354376/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-azure-databricks-pyspark