# How to execute Oracle functions from Pyspark script

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-integration

I have a requirement to execute an Oracle function from Pyspark Script. Is there any way to execute Oracle functions/procedures without using additional python libraries such as cx_Oracle in Pyspark?

Comment: There are no magics. You'll need something that will enable you to connect to Oracle, whether it is a special library or an Oracle odbc/jdbc driver

Comment: Have you seen [this answer on a similar question for Pyspark and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66766115/3061852)?